# Can't use aws-sdk in Meteor

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

For some reason or another, I can't seem to get the AWS SDK to work in Meteor 0.7.0.1.  If I use npm to install, I get the following:

```
While building the application:
node_modules/aws-sdk/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/examples/test.html:1: Can't set     DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/aws-sdk/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/LICENSE-W3C.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/console.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/s3upload.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/tests.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/aws-sdk/dist-tools/browser-builder.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

If I install globally (-g flag), I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
```

I have also tried installing meteor-aws-sdk and aws-sdk-npm neither of which seem to work... Currently I'm trying to use the line:

```
Npm.require( 'aws-sdk' );
```

to import the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've installed the module using `npm`. Meteor doesn't support npm modules installed this way. You need to use a wrapper such as the `npm` package on atmosphere.

You can install `aws-sdk` using meteorite. There is an up to date package up on atmosphere: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/aws-sdk

Comment: Well don't I feel silly, I knew I'd tried this, but I neglected the documentation, so I was trying to call Npm.require( 'aws-sdk' ); not realizing that it was already included because of the smart package.  Thanks a lot!